# Plotting A0 to Z....var in a GeoJson layer using turfjs and leaflet

Tags: geometry, leaflet, geospatial, geojson

I am using turfjs and leaflet to plot a grid and label each square in this fashion:

```
[A0,A1,...,A23]
[B0,B1,...,B23]
[C0,C1,...,C23]
```

End goal:
To know what are the coordinates of the corner points of each cell. I mean, I want to know what are the coordinates of the 4 corners of A0 ( and the other cells ).This will then be fed to a json file with something like this:

```
[
  {"A0": [
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"]
  ]},
  {"A1": [
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"],
    ["x","y"]
  ]}
]
```

Then, my app will ask the GPS from the device and learn which "square" i'm in.

I have managed to plot the squares ( [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jarodium/m59edo7p/), but could not label them or even summon a click to console to find out what are the corner coordinates. I have console'd out the layers but i'm not sure if the plot of the geoJson layer is plotted from left to right. I have concluded each layer spits out 5 coordinates which I suspect that is the information I require but there is a 5th coordinate which does not make sense to be in a square grid cell, unless the 3rd coordinate is the center...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What kind of geodetic grid are you trying to implement?

Comment: Hmmm... Let me try to clarify... I'm not using the same grid that US Military or any WGS system ( as far as my knowlegde goes ). Just want to draw a square on Point A to Point B, and then make a squared grid out of it. You can check  the fiddle. I have already attained the grid goal. Now, for the upper most and left most square ( pos 0,0 ), I want to know the coordinates that form that square, and label it A0. Then, at the next square ( pos 0,1 ), I want to know the coordinates that form that square and label A1, and so on.

Comment: The GeoJSON specification requires that geometries of type Polygon have arrays of coordinates forming rings, with each ring (array) first coordinates pair repeated as the last pair as well. Hence 5 pairs for a square, the last one being equal to the first.

Comment: For reference: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the mystery of the GeoJson layer in leaflet.
The coordinates are returned like this:

```
[ 0, 3 , 6 ]
[ 1, 4 , 7 ]
[ 2, 5 , 8 ]

//will label this way:

A0 = 0 ( coordinate sets at 0 )
A1 = 1 ( coordinate sets at 1 )
A2 = 2
B0 = 3
B1 = 4
B2 = 5
...
```

I still don't know why there is a 5th coordinate in each layer plotted by leaflet. but this is good enough for me. I can know label them as I want.

Thank you for the help.